# Restrict access to an xml file (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

I keep getting a 404 after a 20 second request when I want to simply 403 a path request via htaccess.

In my htaccess I place this at the bottom:

```
<Files /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

How can I do this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files directive only work with files on a per directory basis. That's why you're getting a 404.

> The  directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives by
>   filename.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files

Put this inside an .htaccess file inside the `autodiscover` directory.

```
<Files "autodiscover.xml">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Or you can use a rewriterule in your htaccess file in the `root` directory.

```
RewriteRule ^/?autodiscover/autodiscover\.xml$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Your rewrite rule works (it's not an actual directory, but a route in my CMS). However, I still have to wait 20 seconds for the 403 response (on my local host). Why isn't this instant?

Comment: Is there a delay when accessing the site? That is not really a problem of this rule however. You might need to do additional debugging.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to ignore all requests to autodiscover.xml for whatever reason, say for example they fill up your log files with stupid requests or keep hitting your custom CMS 404 page. You can simply respond with a very small `204 No Content` header like in this `htaccess` example:

`Redirect 204 /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`

Why? A 204 response is cacheable by default. A 4xx header may or may not be cached.